# How to iterate and add elements to a list in scala without changing state

Tags: scala, playframework, functional-programming

I have this

```
val x = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
```

I want to take the items of the list from 3 to the end of the list and create a new list with them without changing state,
and get this:

```
List(4,5,6,7,8,9)
```

Comment: Quite simply: `val ys = x drop 3`.

Comment: @Jubobs wow cool thanks that works fine, it seems a little bit magic to me do you have any reference where i can see the drop implementation behind? :) thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in [@Jubobs' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36343563/how-to-iterate-and-add-elements-to-a-list-in-scala-without-changing-state#comment60309056_36343563) and [@Yuval Itzchakov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36344461/2988), the answer is to use the [`scala.collection.immutable.List.drop(n: Int): List[A]`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@drop(n:Int):List[A]) method of lists, whose implementation you can find in [`src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L218-L226).

However, because of the importance of `List` in the Scala ecosystem, this method is aggressively optimized for performance and not indicative of good Scala style. In particular, even though it is "externally pure", it *does* use mutation, side-effects and loops on the *inside*.

An alternative implementation that *doesn't* use any mutation, loops or side-effects might look like this:

```
override def drop(n: Int): List[A] = 
  if (n == 0) this else tail drop n-1
```

This is the trivial recursive implementation. Note: this will throw an exception if you try to drop more items than the list has, while the original one will handle that gracefully by returning the empty list. Re-introducing that behavior is trivial, though:

```
override def drop(n: Int): List[A] = 
  if (n == 0 || isEmpty) this else tail drop n-1
```

This method is not just recursive, but actually [tail-recursive](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TailRecursion), so it will be as efficient as a `while` loop. We can have the compiler yell at us if that isn't true by adding the [`@scala.annotation.tailrec`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.annotation.tailrec) annotation to the method:

```
@scala.annotation.tailrec override def drop(n: Int): List[A] = 
  if (n == 0 || isEmpty) this else tail drop n-1
```

Comment: Great answer! I would claim that this recursive version is also clearer.

Comment: That's often what happens when code is (micro-)optimized for performance: it becomes less readable and less clear. Note: I just realized that neither `List` nor `List.drop` are `final`, so, *my* version will *not* be tail-recursion-optimized and thus blow the stack for larger lists, which is obviously unacceptable for the standard library version.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, `List.drop` does exactly that:

```
val x = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
val reduced = x.drop(3)
```

The implementation looks like this:

```
override def drop(n: Int): List[A] = {
   var these = this
   var count = n
   while (!these.isEmpty && count > 0) {
     these = these.tail
     count -= 1
   }
   these
}
```